# Rotate string program using either loops or conditionals

Tags: javascript, rotation

I am currently on the early stages of learning JS and I am trying to create a simple program that takes a
string and rotates it. What I mean is that it takes the las caracter and puts it on the front and so on until you have a full circle.
I have seen some solutions way different than what I had in mind. I've been trying to do it with a while and if's. So while(string==string.length) do X.

I have this little piece of code with pop and unshift. And I want to print to console the full circle.

```
let string = Array.from('w3resource');

let removeLast = string.pop();
console.log(removeLast);
let insertFirst = string.unshift(removeLast);
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your start is good, you need now to iterate over the array as you said.

```
let string = Array.from('w3resource');

for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    let removeLast = string.pop();
    let insertFirst = string.unshift(removeLast);
    console.log(string);
}

VM355:6 (10) ["e", "w", "3", "r", "e", "s", "o", "u", "r", "c"]
VM355:6 (10) ["c", "e", "w", "3", "r", "e", "s", "o", "u", "r"]
VM355:6 (10) ["r", "c", "e", "w", "3", "r", "e", "s", "o", "u"]
VM355:6 (10) ["u", "r", "c", "e", "w", "3", "r", "e", "s", "o"]
VM355:6 (10) ["o", "u", "r", "c", "e", "w", "3", "r", "e", "s"]
VM355:6 (10) ["s", "o", "u", "r", "c", "e", "w", "3", "r", "e"]
VM355:6 (10) ["e", "s", "o", "u", "r", "c", "e", "w", "3", "r"]
VM355:6 (10) ["r", "e", "s", "o", "u", "r", "c", "e", "w", "3"]
VM355:6 (10) ["3", "r", "e", "s", "o", "u", "r", "c", "e", "w"]
```

edit for while loop:

```
let string = Array.from('w3resource');
let j = 0;
while (j < string.length) {
    let removeLast = string.pop();
    let insertFirst = string.unshift(removeLast);
    console.log(string);
    j++;
}
```

later edit:

you can also do this pretty straight forward with  `.reverse()` from Array. But this wont be incremental so you cannot log line by line. But you could reimplement reveres functionally with `.map()`

```
Array.from('w3resource').reverse()
(10) ["e", "c", "r", "u", "o", "s", "e", "r", "3", "w"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looking at your code I realized that I was very close to completion but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @JordiCortés if you found teh answer useful do not forget to upvote answeres.

Comment: when I try to upvote I get this message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score -1):

As your wokring with an array that you've created from `w3resource` string,you can use `const` instead of let for storing values because `arrays` manipulations are done througt their reference.

```
const wordToRotate="w3resource".split("")//With split, you can define a delimiter.
```

The problem with a full circle is that the rotation will give you the exact same string at the end

To have something more `flexible`, i'll recommande you using a function to which you can have `2 parameters`:

1. The array that you want to rotate
2. The number of rotation that you want to perform

If you know the basic of how `functions` work,you can create to reusable king of functions.One for a `left rotation` where you `shift` items or remove items at the very left or the begining of an array the `push` at the and or a `right rotation` where you remove `items` from the `very right` or `end` of the `array` with the `pop() method` and and the into the begining by the `unshift method`.

Left rotation

```
function rotateLeft(arr, numberOfRotations) {
  const arrayToRotate = [...arr];

  for (let rotationCount = 1; rotationCount <= numberOfRotations; rotationCount++) {
    const itemToRemoveAtTheLeft = arrayToRotate.shift();
    arrayToRotate.push(itemToRemoveAtTheLeft);
  }
  return arrayToRotate;
}
```

Right rotation

```
 function rotateRight(arr, numberOfRotations) {
  const arrayToRotate = [...arr];

  for (let rotationCount = 1; rotationCount <= numberOfRotations; rotationCount++) {
    const itemToRemoveAtTheLeft = arrayToRotate.pop();
    arrayToRotate.unshift(itemToRemoveAtTheLeft);
  }
  return arrayToRotate;
}
```

Now you can call the `function` that you want:

```
const charArray="w3resource".split("")//Or const charArray=Array.from("w3resource")
```

`rotateLeft(charArray,3)` or `rotateRight(charArray,3)`

I hope that it helps

Comment: This solution is more flexible and reusable